# Why is evaluation of this python code block disabled in emacs org mode?

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode, evaluation

In a python source block in org-mode, after hitting C-c C-c, emacs says

> Evaluation of python source block is disabled

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Do you have a minimal working example (i.e., a small code source block) that we could all try out to reproduce your exact issue?

Answer (score 11):

Simon's answer is not right if the org-mode version is >= 9. Here is another [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28441/org-mode-9-unable-to-eval-code-blocks) on the same problem.

The solution

```
cd .emacs.d
cd elpa
cd org-xxxx
rm *.elc
```

Then, it's better to byte-recompile the directory of the org-xxxx. To do that, start emacs, then

```
C-0 M-x byte-recompile-directory RET ~/emacs.d/elpa/org-xxxx
```

Details at [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641).

Update 1: [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompiledFile) on compile file.

Comment: The link on the last line of your answer seems to be dead.

Comment: @Nick the link is to https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641  I just checked it, it should work. BTW, More specifically, it is [this_comment](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7641#issuecomment-262498640)

Comment: Yup, it's working: whatever was happening yesterday (locally or remotely) seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 2):

In order to evaluate an org-mode code block of a specific language you will have to customize `org-babel-load-languages` as described [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html#configure). Evaluating the following will probably resolve your issue:

```lisp
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)))
```

From the docs:

> `org-babel-load-languages` is a variable defined in `org.el`.
>   Original value was `((emacs-lisp . t))`
>
> Languages which can be evaluated in Org-mode buffers. This list can be used to load support for any of the languages below, note that each language will depend on a different set of system executables and/or Emacs modes.  When a language is "loaded", then code blocks in that language can be evaluated with `org-babel-execute-src-block` bound by default to `C-c C-c` (note the `org-babel-no-eval-on-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` variable can be set to remove code block evaluation from the `C-c C-c` keybinding.  By default only Emacs Lisp (which has no requirements) is loaded.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 24.1 of Emacs.